# JS Getter performance

Tags: javascript, performance

I am wondering, does using a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) in JS create a reference to this function or would it be more performant to assign to a variable and using this instead?

### Using a Getter

```
{
   get jamie (){
      //runs some complex stuff
   }
}
```

### Using named variables

```
const hutber = () => {
   //runs some complex stuff
}

{
   jamie: hutber()
}
```

Comment: Your two snippets are not the same. The getter is called lazily when the property is accessed, **every time** the property is accessed. The second snippet computes the value for `jamie` once when the object is created and stores it.

Comment: Note that your code produces two different behaviours: the getter is evaluated at "call time" while your ***using named variables*** is called at "construction time".

In the first case every time you call `myObject.jamie` it evaluates the function, while in the second you evaluate `hutber` function just once the `myObject` is created

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by the getter "*create a reference to this function*". A getter *is* a function. However, you don't have to explicitly call it, reading a property executes that function. Whether or not you execute a function as `obj.foo` (getter) or `obj.bar()` (method call) I am not sure the difference in *the call* matters. It's worth asking yourself - is this actually a bottleneck? See [Which is faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: I think this was the key point I missed in the documentation. I assumed/thought it was possible that JS would create the getter's function and then reference that with each call of the object. hutber will also get executed with each object call too, however the function will not have to be created with each call... I think this means its quicker

Answer (score 0):

Getters are methods that get and return the internal properties of an object and allows you to return different values using conditionals:

```js
const person = {
  _firstName: 'John',
  _lastName: 'Doe',
  get fullName() {
    if (this._firstName && this._lastName){
      return `${this._firstName} ${this._lastName}`;
    } else {
      return 'Missing a first name or a last name.';
    }
  }
}

// call the getter method: 
person.fullName; // 'John Doe'
```

Notice that in the getter method above:

```
We use the get keyword followed by a function.
We use an if...else conditional to check if both _firstName and _lastName exist (by making sure they both return truthy values) and then return a different value depending on the result.
We can access the calling object’s internal properties using this. In fullName, we’re accessing both this._firstName and this._lastName.
In the last line we call fullName on person. In general, getter methods do not need to be called with a set of parentheses. Syntactically, it looks like we’re accessing a property.
```

Now that we’ve gone over syntax, let’s discuss some notable advantages of using getter methods:

```
Getters can perform an action on the data when getting a property.
Getters can return different values using conditionals.
In a getter, we can access the properties of the calling object using this.
The functionality of our code is easier for other developers to understand.
```